# How to upload one more file in same hash of IPFS

Tags: file-upload, next.js, blockchain, ipfs

I have created a website to upload a single image on IPFS and generate hash for it .

Now I want to upload a folder of 2 or more images, I did with pinata but I want to upload it through my website

THIS IS HTML (APP.TSX)

```html
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
  <input type="file" multiple webkitdirectory mozdirectory />
  <input type="submit" className="button-62" />
</form>
```

THIS IS ON-SUBMIT FUNCTION

```js
const onSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const form = e.target as HTMLFormElement;
  const files = (form[0] as HTMLInputElement).files;

  if (!files || files.length === 0) {
    return alert("No file selected");
  }

  const filesAsArray = Array.from(files);

  if (filesAsArray[0].webkitRelativePath === "") {
    // files or bunch of files
    filesAsArray.forEach(async (file: any, index: number) => {
      const result = await (ipfs as IPFSHTTPClient).add(file);
      console.log("results-cid : ", result.cid);
      console.log("results-path : ", result.path);
      console.log(`full-url : https://ipfs.io/ipfs/${result.path}`);
      setUploadedFile([
        ...uploadedFile,
        {
          cid: result.cid,
          path: result.path,
        },
      ]);
    });
  } else {
    filesAsArray.forEach(async (file: any, index: number) => {
      console.log("file", file);
      const result = await (ipfs as IPFSHTTPClient).add(
        {
          path: `images/${file.name}`,
          content: file,
        }
      );
      console.log("result", result);
      console.log("results-cid : ", result.cid);
      console.log("results-path : ", result.path);
    });
  }
};
```

THIS IS OUTPUT IN CONSOLE

```
folder
App.tsx:64 file File {name: '1.jpg', lastModified: 1649998567608, lastModifiedDate: Fri Apr 15 2022 10:26:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: 'images/1.jpg', size: 102265, …}
App.tsx:63 folder
App.tsx:64 file File {name: '2.jpg', lastModified: 1651732741324, lastModifiedDate: Thu May 05 2022 12:09:01 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: 'images/2.jpg', size: 19522, …}
App.tsx:71 result {path: 'images', cid: CID, size: 102332}
App.tsx:72 results-cid :  CID {code: 112, version: 0, multihash: Digest, bytes: Uint8Array(34), byteOffset: 0, …}
App.tsx:73 results-path :  images
App.tsx:71 result {path: 'images', cid: CID, size: 19589}
App.tsx:72 results-cid :  CID {code: 112, version: 0, multihash: Digest, bytes: Uint8Array(34), byteOffset: 0, …}
App.tsx:73 results-path :  images
```

[image: THIS HASH IS CONTAINING ONLY ONE IMAGE]

Basically, it is generating two hashes (node/directory) and storing both in images in these two different directories. I want to store both the images in same directory:

**HASH 1 QmSK11ykHorPMxkwXQvj61Y2UoWxvJG7UdVhH8zTUmJ1hZ**

**HASH 2 QmWCjf19j3zZXAgjkRW1W2c5kECXEpWWYmSoUHq6XVw6t9**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IPFS JavaScript client, you might as well try the Mutable File System API, basically allowing you think of IPFS as a file system (Note that `file.path` was just to demonstrate that you put a path there):

```js
await ipfs.files.mkdir('/path/to/imageDir')
files.forEach(async (file) => {
  await ipfs.files.cp(file.path, `/path/to/imageDir/${file.name}`)
})
const { cid, type } = await ipfs.files.stat('/path/to/imageDir')
```

Check out the [doc](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/core-api/FILES.md#ipfsfilesmkdirpath-options) for more info.

Alternatively, you can try [web3.storage directory wrapping API](https://web3.storage/docs/how-tos/store#directory-wrapping) which gives you a nice abstraction over IPFS.